# calling function from datepicker.js file but error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, css, daterangepicker

I want to call a function which is in `app.js` from `datepicker.js` file on the click of a button but it is showing error...It's showing the function is not defined. The error is

> Uncaught Referrence: submitDetails is not defined

**app.js**

```js
 clickApply: function(e) {
            
            console.log("hi&hello");
            submitDetails();
            
            this.hide();
            this.element.trigger('apply.daterangepicker', this);
  }
```

**datepicker.js**

```js
$scope.submitDetails=function(){
                        
                        var k= $scope.timeRangeValue;

                        console.log('In K', k);
                        k= k.split("-");
                        console.log('sec k', k);
                        k[0]= k[0].split("/").join("-");
                        console.log(k[0]);
                        k[1]= k[1].split("/").join("-");
                        console.log(k[1]);
                        var s1 = k[0].split(" ");
                        var s2 = k[1].split(" ");
                        $scope.final1 = s1[0] + "T" + s1[1] + "Z"
                        $scope.final2 = s2[1] + "T" + s2[2] + "Z"
                        console.log($scope.final1);
                        console.log($scope.final2);
                        
                        $scope.requestDataFrEvents();
                        
                    }
```

Comment: post your code here

Comment: Posting the error you get is also helpful.

Comment: corrected formatting

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make sure the scripts are loaded in the correct order.
If i remember correctly it should be like this:
1. moment.js
2. daterangepicker.js
3. your script.js

I would make a bundle of them and load them at the bottom of the page.
Hope that helps!